# Manipulate fragment of user selection (javascript)

Tags: javascript, range, getselection

I've got the following function:

```
function manipulateSelection() {
        if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
        var selection = window.getSelection ();
        if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = selection.getRangeAt (0);
            var fragment = range.extractContents();
            /*

            manipulate fragment here 

            */
            range.insertNode(fragment);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange (range);
        }
        else alert("nothing selected");
    }
    else alert("browser not supported");
}
```

I want to manipulate the fragment of user selected text. But without manipulating the fragment my code already breaks if the selection exeeds multiple tags.

For example:

```
<p>lorem i<selection>psum</p><p>dolor</selection> sit amet</p>
```

Results in:

```
<p>lorem i</p><p>psum</p><p>dolor</p><p> sit amet</p>
```

While I want it to stay the same (if I don't manipulate it).

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QebpX/1/

Comment: What do you actually want to do with the selection?

Comment: I want to make the text bold with execCommand and change the created <b> tag to <strong> (if the browser created a <b> tag). And I don't need support for older browsers (< IE 9).

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the range first and manipulate on the cloned range and then insert it into the selection if you have manipulated it

```
    function manipulateSelection() {
    if (window.getSelection) {  // all browsers, except IE before version 9
    var selection = window.getSelection ();
    if (selection.rangeCount > 0) {
        var range = selection.getRangeAt (0);

        var temp_range = range.cloneRange();
        var temp_fragment = temp_range.extractContents();
        /*
        manipulate fragment here 

        */
        if(manipulated)
        {
          var fragment = range.extractContent();
          range.insertNode(temp_fragment);
          selection.removeAllRanges();
          selection.addRange (range);
        }   
    }
    else alert("nothing selected");
  }
 else alert("browser not supported");
```

}

Comment: I might be missing something, but this gives the same result as the code I created myself... If you select multiple paragraphs an extra paragraph is created.